# How to create a makefile without having to include every single source file in the project?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm taking some C++ classes and have send the teacher 9 exercises, each exercise is a simple directory with the name 'ex$' where $ is the number. Each directory has a single source file named 'ex$.cpp. I want  to create a makefile that will allow me to type:

```
make ex$
```

And it will build a executable that corresponds to the compiled source file inside 'ex$' directory. The catch is that I want to do that without creating a target for each exercise(Some kind of 'generic target'). I also need to have an 'all' target that will go into each directory starting with 'ex' and build the executable there. How can I do that?

Comment: what about `find -name *.cpp | xargs g++`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your C++ targets can be built with essentially the same command, you can do this fairly easily. Read [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). Look for `$@`, in particular. Since this is part of an education, I'll leave the rest vague.

Answer (score 2):

Can I also suggest looking at CMake which will make better makefiles for you to use IMO. Initial high learning curve for major long term gain. :)